# Polar Coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

It's been ages since i did any coordinate conversions, and typically i have these two which i just can't manage to solve by myself.

1. I want to express the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}<4, x<0 $
2. The Area:  $x-|y|\ge 0$

For the first problem i just thought it would be as easy as following:

$$0< r < 2$$

$$\frac {\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

For the second problem i don't even know how to begin...

Best Regards

Joe

Answer (score 1):

For the second problem: $-\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ ($x \geq |y|$ hence $x$ is positive, $\cos\theta \geq |\sin\theta|$, from which the inequality for $\theta$ easily follows).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you get started. Here's a picture of the region $x-|y|\geq0$:

$\hskip2in$[image]

([generated here by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=region+plot+x-+Abs%5By%5D+%3E%3D0%2C+-15%3C%3Dx%3C%3D15%2C+-15%3C%3Dy%3C%3D15)). From this picture, there's something you should be able to see immediately: will there be any dependence on $r$? In fact, can you work out what the region is from the picture?

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply! Allthough i dont think i really understand what you mean by dependency of r.

Comment: You mean the highllighted area i assume. Italien that part om having difficulties expressing in polar cooedinates

Comment: @Joe: I mean, does the question "Is the point $(r,\theta)$ in the region?" depend on what $r$ is?